# C# - Try-Catch Excessive CPU on .Net Framework Functions

Tags: c#

[image]

Im using a loop that connects to many servers with TCP Streams and such.
Whenever one of those Streams has a general exception like IOExceptions, it returns debug information to System.Diagnostics.Debug causing a lot of CPU.

I had a similar issue with this before where exceptions caused a lot of CPU. I removed the code and replaced it with a function bool return system, where instead of throwing an exception, it would just return true/false, true = went fine, false = error occured. This would be possible because some of the functions were either asynchronous and I could Wait on them and return true/false or it just returned as a bool.

But for streams I dont have that option.

[image]

Due to where its being caught and thrown, I dont think there's anyway to really mitigate this issue?

I essentially just need to ignore exceptions thrown by a command and not have them be thrown.
Is there a way to override that function and just change it up a bit?

Comment: exceptions are taxing on a cpu. they have to context switch.

Comment: @DanielA.White Right, but im expecting 100's of them per minute which takes a huge toll on CPU performance. So is there nothing really that can be done?

Comment: share your code and i'm guessing someone might be able to help i dont do much w/ tcp sockets directly.

Comment: Hundreds per *minute* shouldn't cause a problem. Hundreds per *second* more so, hundreds per *millisecond* would be reasonably significant I suspect. (CPUs can do an awful lot of work in a minute...) Have you measured how many you're actually experiencing?

Comment: @DaisyShipton Getting about 13,000 every 3 minutes. https://i.imgur.com/GP0JfUP.png

Comment: @DanielA.White: Why would a language exception cause a context switch?  Searching for handlers and unwinding the stack are all user-mode operations.  Only conversion of processor traps to language exceptions requires kernel help and context switching, but stream error processing doesn't involve processor traps.

Comment: I'd agree that 13,000 per 3 minutes smells like something to be avoided, but I still wouldn't expect it to peg the CPU. A quick test on my laptop managed to throw and catch 13,000 exceptions (each with a stack depth of 1000) in about 200ms, which is tiny. Now that's only a microbenchmark, but there'd have to be a *huge* discrepancy for that to be a significant factor...

Comment: @DaisyShipton Im using it on a .Wait() and in multiple different areas of code. That might be a factor. Also its not the speed im worried about but the CPU usage. Beforehand I would have this amount of CPU usage for something similar, but as said in the OP, I changed it all from throw x; to return false/true; and it worked a ton better, reducing CPU usage drastically. Less exceptions were being thrown on it then this one too.

Comment: You might want to investigate what's going on *other* than the exception then. It's entirely possible that other aspects of the execution path that leads to an exception are taking time. Looking back at your question, you've talked about "Whenever one of those Streams has a general exception like IOExceptions, it returns debug information to System.Diagnostics.Debug causing a lot of CPU." Are you running a debug build? Do you observe the same CPU load in a release build?

Comment: @DaisyShipton It is a debug build yes, and seemingly the same on a release build. As far as I can tell, its the exceptions. Dont wanna point blame or anything, but it seems like it. There is other functions that cause a chunk of CPU like .ConnectToHost(host, port) which I use to connect to a proxy. Maybe its something from that?

Comment: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html

Comment: @ImPRAGMA: On a release build, any calls to `Debug.WriteLine` etc should be omitted entirely. But yes, setting up thousands of connections could be CPU-intensive, particularly if there's any crypto involved. Now would be a good time to try to isolate different aspects of the behavior to work out the true cause of the load.

Comment: @DaisyShipton Isolate as in functions for parts of code? Would make sense.

Comment: @ImPRAGMA: More trying to take bits out (e.g. logging) and measure the CPU load in each case as far as possible. I acknowledge it may be very messy - it's hard to tell without more context. But once you have more idea what's expensive, it'll be easier to consider the ways forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task.Wait Huge CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097664/task-wait-huge-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 1):

The OS functions use return values and the thread last-error state, no exceptions.  So you could use p/invoke to call the API directly and handle the return value, avoiding the exception overhead.

It's a considerable amount of work to rewrite from `NetworkStream` code to sockets APIs, so I'd suggest proving that this is a major problem (using a profiler) before doing it.

---

Another option, if you don't mind using undocumented internals, is to use the fact that the `IAsyncResult` object is actually a `System.Net.LazyAsyncResult` containing an `ErrorCode` property.  Reading that is possible using the magic of reflection, however reflection is possibly even slower than exception handling, so you'd need to do the reflection once and then save a delegate for future use.

Note that the framework code does two things when it recognizes an error code.

- Adjusts/cleans up internal state
- Throws an exception

If you circumvent this by inspecting the error code yourself, you'll also need to call the undocumented method that does the cleanup.  In the case of `EndConnect`, that's `UpdateStatusAfterSocketError` on the `TcpClient`'s internal `Socket` instance.

Less work than rewriting everything with p/invoke, but more fragile because it relies on implementation details that Microsoft could change in the future.